# Prove this by contradiction

Tags: inequality

Prove that

$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}\,\,\exists\,x,y\in[0,1]\,:
|xy-ax-by|\geq\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: @Chinny84 There is no requirement for $x=y=0$ to satisfy the inequality.

Comment: @MathIsFun7225 ah I understand the original question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|a| \geq \frac{1}{3}$, then one can take $x = 1$ and $y = 0$.

If $|b| \geq \frac{1}{3}$, then one can take $x = 0$ and $y = 1$.

If $|a|$ and $|b|$ are both smaller than $\frac{1}{3}$, then one can take $x = 1$ and $y = 1$, so that $|1 - a - b| \geq 1 - \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$.

---

EDIT: Sorry I didn't see that the title said "prove by contradiction".

So just reword it a little bit:

Assume there is $a, b$ such that for any $x, y\in[0, 1]$, we have $|xy - ax - by| < \frac{1}{3}$.

Taking $(x, y) = (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)$ respectively, we get:
\begin{eqnarray*}
|a| &<& \frac{1}{3}\\
|b| &<& \frac{1}{3}\\
|1-a-b| &<& \frac{1}{3}
\end{eqnarray*}
Adding the three gives a contradiction:
$$1 = |a + b + (1 - a - b)| \leq |a| + |b| + |1 - a - b| < \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you for both answers!

Comment: You are welcome. You could support my answer by selecting it as the correct answer.